# Performs calculation with operators given in an unknown order

Tags: c++, performance, calculator, interpreter

**Problem Statement**

Write a simple interpreter which understands "+", "-", and "*" `operations`. Apply the operations with the correct order of operations (i.e. multiply, then add or subtract) using command/arg pairs starting with the initial value of `value`. The commands will not necessarily be given in the correct order of operations.

Arguments given: `int value`, `vector<char> operations`, `vector<int> args`

**My Solution (C++)**

```
int simpleInterpreter(int value, vector<char> operations, vector<int> args) {
    int index = 0;

    for (char operation : operations) {
        if (operation == '*') {
            value *= args[index];
        index++;
        }
    }

    for (char operation : operations) {
        if (operation == '+') {
            value += args[index];
        index++;
        } else if (operation == '-') {
            value -= args[index];
            index++;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Example cases:

- `simpleInterpreter(0, {'+', '+', '*'}, {5000000, 1, 2}) => 3`
- `simpleInterpreter(1, {'*', '-', '*', '+'}, {-1, -1, 1, 1) => 1`
- `simpleInterpreter(45, {'+', '*', '-'}, {2, 90, 180}) => 0`
- `simpleInterpreter(100, {'+', '+', '*'}, {0, 5, 2}) => 7`

I'm not really concerned about having safe input / I don't care about bad input. I'm mostly focused on readability and performance here.

Is this a good solution? What can be improved? Another solution I thought of would be to build a custom comparator and store the operations into a set of pairs (operator, how many times it appears), however this would increase space complexity without reducing time complexity so I didn't do that.

Comment: The problem is badly stated. It can either mean you should apply basic math priority of evaluate all multiplications/divisions before addition/substractions, which is a rather strange form of math. You should double check if this is indeed what is mean, as you implemented the latter more uncommon version. To be sure commands in the wrong order could also mean  {+,4} { *, 5} , as the * would be evaluated first.

Comment: I actually came up with the problem, I'm sorry that you think I stated it poorly. Do you have an suggestions for how I could improve the statement? I only came up with the problem while working on a similar problem, but I wanted to add the additional difficulty of using normal mathematical order of operations without being given the operations in the correct order. Also, if you can think of any clever algorithms (as per your bio) I would be super happy to hear them!

Comment: You should check out the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: Or you could implement partial Shunting Yard, with just reordering the tokens into two subsets and doing double pass: eliminate all multiply signs, then the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this task rather bizarre, but anyway…

The function signature should probably be

```
int simpleInterpreter(int value, const std::vector<char> &operations, const std::vector<int> &args)
```

Instead of writing separate `index++;` statements, I'd roll them into a post-increment operator:

```
value *= args[index++];
```

To be clear that `index` refers to the `args` vector, I'd rename `index` to `argIndex`.

Comment: I see, thank you! Those are some small yet useful tips that I hadn't considered. Do you have anything to say for the overall solution itself? Like, maybe a more elegant way of solving this problem?

Comment: I already said all I have to say. I would have approached the problem in pretty much the same way.

Comment: Don't place the `&` next to the value. Its part of the type. This is not C code.